# Applying Dark Theme in Android Studio to every activity

Tags: android-studio, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

So I know how to use a switch to activate and deactivate Dark Theme in Android Studio. I currently have that feature in a settings activity I created. I can't seem to find an answer to how I can apply that to all my activities though. So if there is a way to do this I would love to know how I could go about setting this up.